# How to solve this bivariate recurrence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have run into this recurrence relation while trying to solve a problem in probability.

$$
g(r, s) = pg(r - 1, s) + qg(r, s - 1)
$$

$$
g(0, s) = 1, g(r, 0) = 0
$$

So far I have concluded that

$$
g(r, s) = \sum_{k = 0}^{s}\binom{r}{k}p^{r - k}q^{k}g(k, s - k)
$$

But I'm not sure where to go now...

Comment: $q=1-p$, right?

Comment: Does not matter anyway. What I suggest: using your recursion, write $g(r,s)$ in a table, starting with $g(1,1)=p, g(2,1)=p^2, g(1,2)=p(1+q)$, etc. After filling enough values, you will be able to guess the formula, and then prove it by induction. It will involve sums of powers of $p$ and $q$ with some binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Define the bivariate generating function
 $$G(x, y) = \sum_{\substack{r \ge 0 \\
                            s \ge 0}} g(r, s) x^r y^s$$,
shift indices and write:

$\begin{align}
g(r + 1, s + 1)
  = p g(r, s + 1) + q g(r + 1, s)
\end{align}$

Multiply by $x^r y^s$, sum over $r \ge 0, s \ge 0$ and get:

$\begin{align}
\frac{G(x, y) - G(0, y) - G(x, 0) + G(0, 0)}{x y}
  = p \frac{G(x, y) - G(x, 0)}{y}
     + q \frac{G(x, y) - G(0, y)}{x}
\end{align}$

Now you need boundary conditions:

$\begin{align}
G(x, 0)
  &= \sum_{r \ge 0} g(r, 0) x^r \\
  &= 0 \\
G(0, y)
  &= \sum_{s \ge 0} g(0, s) y^s \\
  &= \frac{1}{1 - y}
\end{align}$

Solving for $G(x, y)$:

$\begin{align}
G(x, y)
  &= \frac{1 - q y}
          {1 - p x - (1 - q) y + p x y + q y^2} \\
  &= \frac{1 - q y}{(1 - y) (1 - p x - q y)} \\
  &= \frac{1 - q}{1 - q - p x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - y}
       + \frac{p q x}{1 - q - p x} \frac{1}{1 - p x - q y}
\end{align}$

Now you can expand as geometric series in $y$, and expand the resulting terms again in $x$. You'll get a double sum, out of which to pick the coefficient of $x^r y^s$.